# Prove $x$ is rational if $x = 0.a_1a_2a_3\dots$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

source: BMO2 2004 q4

The real number $x$ between $0$ and $1$ has decimal representation $0.a_1a_2a_3a_4\dots$
And enjoys the following property: the number of distinct blocks of the form $a_k$$a_{k+1}$$a_{k+2}$ … $a_{k+2003}$,

as $k$ ranges through the positive integers, is less than or equal to $2004$. Prove that $x$ is rational.

I try to prove by induction. Claim: For any positive integer n, if there are at most n different blocks of length n, then the number is rational. When n=1, if a1=a, then every digit is a and the number 0.aaa… = a x 0.111… = a/9 is rational. Assume n = m-1 is true, Consider the number x in question. If there are fewer than n different blocks of length n-1, then x is rational. (n=m-1 is true) If there are at least n different blocks of length n-1. I don't know how to proceed....

Comment: I try to prove by induction.  Claim: For any positive integer n, if there are at most n different blocks of length n, then the number is rational. 
When n=1, if a1=a, then every digit is a and the number 
0.aaa…   = a x 0.111… = a/9   is rational.
Assume n = m-1 is true, 
Consider the number x in question.  
If there are fewer than n different blocks of length n-1, then x is rational.   (n=m-1 is true)
If there are at least n different blocks of length n-1.  I don't know how to proceed....

Comment: Continued fractions might help.

Comment: I've also tried this problem, and it comes down to showing that at some point the decimals start to repeat. To get the intuition for a proof, think about what must happen after we reach our "limit"; that is, what happens after we have "used up" all $2004$ blocks of integers. If you follow this logic through, it's not too hard to see that the blocks must start to repeat, at which point you know it is rational.

Comment: @Roskiller can you please add some details... I have been thinking about this problem since afternoon, and I have an idea similar to yours, but I can't make it work. I can *feel* there is some sort of PHP necessary, but I can't complete it

Comment: @SayanDutta, the OP hasn't been seen for more than two years. If you have an idea, why not ask in a separate post of your own? I'm sure your post would be more likely to follow the community guidelines as the OP seems to not care anymore.

Comment: @Invisible I really didn't notice that the question is so old, or I would have done that before. Now that the question finally has an answer, I should probably leave it here...

Answer (score 3):

We prove a more general statement: if a real number $x$ between $0$ and $1$ has decimal representation $x=0.a_1a_2a_3a_4\dots$ (in base $b$) and enjoys the following property: the number of distinct blocks of the form $a_{k+1}a_{k+2}\cdots a_{k+N}$ as $k$ ranges through the positive integers is less than or equal to $N$ (call this number $M$), then $x$ is rational.

Consider the directed graph $G$ defined on $b^N$ vertices. Each vertex corresponds to $N$ ordered naturals from the set $\{0,1,\cdots,b-1\}$ and represent a possible block $a_{k+1}a_{k+2}\cdots a_{k+N}$. A vertex (defined by $(a_{1},a_{2},\cdots, a_{N})$) has an edge directed to another vertex (defined by $(b_{1},b_{2},\cdots, b_{N})$) if

$$b_1=a_2$$

$$b_2=a_3$$

$$\vdots$$

$$b_{N-1}=a_N$$

Thus, $G$ is a directed graph with $b^N$ vertices and $b^{N+1}$ directed edges. Now, consider the subgraph $H$ defined on the $M$ vertices that correspond to the $M$ unique blocks. On this graph $H$, define a clump as any subset of vertices of $H$ with the properties: if $(u,v)$ are elements of a clump $C$ then there exists a path from $u\to v$ and $v\to u$ and if $u$ is in $C$ and $u\to v$ then $v$ is in $C$. For the purposes of this definition, a single vertex that 'dead-ends' (no edge leading out from it) is a clump; however this is impossible since every vertex corresponds to a block, and each block leads to at least $1$ other block (from the definition of decimal expansion of $x$ in base $b$).

Now, can $H$ have multiple clumps? Suppose we have two distinct clumps, $C_1$ and $C_2$. If $u\in C_1$ and $v\in C_2$ then no path can exist from $u$ to $v$ or $v$ to $u$. Suppose that a such a path does exist from $u$ to $v$: by the second property of clumps we may conclude $v\in C_1$. Then either there exists a path from $v\to u$ (contradicting our assumption that $C_1\neq C_2$) or such a path does not exist (contradicting our first property of clumps). But if no path exists, it is impossible to have both vertices $u$ and $v$ correspond to unique blocks. That is, once you hit the unique block corresponding to vertex $u$ you can never hit the unique block corresponding to block $v$ (and vice-versa). This is impossible as $H$ was constructed from vertices corresponding to the unique blocks in the expansion of $x$. We conclude that $H$ has exactly one clump. Additionally, we must eventually find ourselves in this clump as each vertex in it corresponds to a unique block in the expansion of $x$.

As we said above, this clump cannot 'dead-end' in a vertex with no outflow. Thus, the clump has at least one sub-cycle in it (in fact, every vertex in the clump is in a sub-cycle). For the purposes of this definition we are considering the vertex with an edge leading back to itself to be a sub-cycle. Now, imagine an ant crawling on the clump, each move corresponding to a new block in the expansion of $x$. Suppose the path the ant takes eventually becomes the ant traveling around an infinite cycle forever. Then clearly the blocks of $x$ eventually become periodic and therefore $x$ is rational. We will show that if the ants path cannot be described as eventually traveling a single sub-cycle, then the paths length is strictly greater than $N$.

Since the ant does not eventually travel a single sub-cycle, there must be at least two cycles it travels on. Denote one such cycle by the letter $C$. The path leaving and eventually returning to $C$ (perhaps in conjunction with some vertices of $C$) corresponds to a second cycle; call this cycle $R$. Additionally, call the vertex where the cycles meet $S$ and the vertex where they split apart $T$. Of course, it is possible that there are even more cycles attached in numerous ways to $C$ and $R$, but for the purpose of this proof it is sufficient to only consider moves that the ant takes on these cycles (since we only care that the number of vertices in $C$ and $R$ are strictly greater than $N$).

[image: Example of multiple, connected cycles]

Above, you can see an example of multiple, connected cycles. Unlike in the example, it is possible that $S$ and $T$ are the same vertex. Since the ant completes trips around both cycles an infinite number of times, it will be sufficient to show that the total number of vertices is strictly greater than $N$.

Let $c$ be the number of vertices in cycle $C$, $r$ be the number of vertices in cycle $R$, and $w$ be the number of vertices in common. Note that each of $c,r,w\geq 1$. Now, imagine that the ant is sitting on vertex $S$ and looks at the corresponding block: it will look like

$$S:[a_{s}...a_c][a_1a_2...a_c][a_1a_2...a_c]\cdots [a_1a_2...a_c]$$

Here, brackets have been added to emphasize groups of length $c$ and $s$ is defined so that the total amount of numbers in the block is $N$. If $c|N$ then the first set of brackets is empty and we have $N/c$ clean blocks of length $c$ each. The ant then moves to vertex $T$ and looks at the corresponding block

$$T:[a_{s+w-1}...a_c][a_1a_2...a_c][a_1a_2...a_c]\cdots [a_1a_2...a_c][a_1a_2...a_{w-1}]$$

If $w=1$, then the rightmost set of brackets can be treated as empty. Continuing, if the ant chooses to stay on cycle $C$, then the next vertex would have the block

$$[a_{s+w}...a_c][a_1a_2...a_c][a_1a_2...a_c]\cdots [a_1a_2...a_c][a_1a_2...a_{w-1}a_w]$$

If not and the ant instead goes to cycle $R$, the next block becomes

$$[a_{s+w}...a_c][a_1a_2...a_c][a_1a_2...a_c]\cdots [a_1a_2...a_c][a_1a_2...a_{w-1}][q]$$

for some digit $q\neq a_w$. Rearranging the brackets, this block can also be written

$$[a_{s+w}...a_{w-1}a_w][a_{w+1}...a_ca_1a_2...a_{w-1}a_w]...[a_{w+1}...a_ca_1a_2...a_{w-1}a_w][a_{w+1}...a_ca_1a_2...a_{w-1}q]$$

Now, I want to draw attention to the $c$ rightmost digits in the above block

$$a_{w+1}...a_ca_1a_2...a_{w-1}q$$

Can this block appear amongst the following $c$ blocks?

$$a_1a_2...a_{c-1}a_c$$

$$a_2a_3...a_ca_1$$

$$\vdots$$

$$a_ca_1...a_{c-2}a_{c-1}$$

The answer is no since each block in the list above will have $1$ more count of the digit corresponding to $a_w$ than the block with the $a_w$th digit replaced by some other digit (represented by $q$). In fact, this discrepancy can only be rectified once $q$ has moved left through the block to the point where the $c$ left most digits go from

$$a_{w+1}...a_ca_1a_2...a_{w-1}q$$

to

$$a_{w+2}...a_ca_1a_2...a_{w-1}qa_{w+1}$$

An example of this for $c=3$ and $N=6$ is

$$121\ 121\text{ (corresponds to vertex }S\text{)}$$

$$211\ \underline{2}1\overline{2}$$

$$11\underline{2}\ 1\overline{2}1$$

$$121\ \overline{2}11$$

$$\underline{2}1\overline{2}\ 112$$

$$1\bar{2}1\ 121\text{ (corresponds to vertex }T\text{)}$$

Note that the $\overline{2}$ breaks the pattern of $121$ and it only fixes when the $\underline{2}$ leaves the left edge of the block. Counting, this will take at least $N-c+1$ vertices.

---

EDIT: As requested, here is more elaboration of this section of the proof. The digit represented by $q$ replaces the digit represented by $a_w$ at the first vertex in cycle $R$ after vertex $T$ (the vertex where the $C$ and $R$ cycles split apart). As we showed above, once we introduce the digit $q$, we cannot have $q$ end a string of digits of length $c$. That is, since the string

$$a^{'}_{w+1}...a_ca_1a_2...a_{w-1}q$$

never equals any of the following

$$a_1a_2...a_{c-1}a_c$$

$$a_2a_3...a_ca_1$$

$$\vdots$$

$$a_ca_1...a_{c-2}a_{c-1}$$

we are assured that the vertex $S$ does not contain

$$a^{'}_{w+1}...a_ca_1a_2...a_{w-1}q$$

as a substring. Note here that we are denoting the specific instance of $a_{w+1}$ that corresponds to $c-1$ digits before $q$ by $a^{'}_{w+1}$. Thus, it must be the case that by the time we move around cycle $R$ we will have **at least** removed $a^{'}_{w+1}$ from the block. Getting $a^{'}_{w+1}$ to the left most digit of the entire block takes exactly $N-c$ vertices. Adding the first vertex in $R$ where $q$ first appears, we may conclude that $a^{'}_{w+1}$ will move to the end of the block after traversing exactly $N-c+1$ vertices of cycle $R$ (vertices that are not in common with $C$ since we are at the vertex before $S$). Since at least $a^{'}_{w+1}$ has to move off the block, the number of vertices that $R$ does not have in common with $C$ (given by $r-w$) is

$$r-w\geq N-c+1$$

---

Importantly, the $+1$ here counts the initial appearance of $q$ in the block (note that the example above has $4=6-3+1$ vertices between $T$ and $S$). But this is the key piece of our proof! The total number of vertices in $R$ that are **not** shared with $C$ is given by

$$r-w\geq N-c+1$$

Then the total number of vertices is

$$\text{Total number}=r+c-w\geq c+N-c+1= N+1$$

We conclude that if there are at most $N$ unique blocks of length $N$, then $x$ is rational.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I was working out the last step but did not finish the last step. Just asking, did my answer help ? I derived until the periodicity and orbits/graphs. The last inequality $r-w \geq N-c+1$ was the step i missed. Good catch !

Comment: @Balajisb yeah, your answer was good for pointing me in the right direction and thinking about orbits (ie cycles). The trickiest part I found was justifying that $+1$ and most of my graph stuff was just to get a visual representation that I could think about

Comment: Can you please elaborate more on the proof that $r - w \geq N-c+1$ ?

Comment: Just to improve your answer, $(a_1,a_2,...,a_{w-1},q,a_{w+1},...,a_c) = (a_{i+1},a_{i+2},...,a_c,a_1,...,a_{i}) $ $\implies$ $q = a_{w+i \mod c} = a_{w+2i \mod c} = .. =  a_{w+\ell i \mod c}  = a_w$ for some $\ell$. Hence $q = a_w$ which is contradiction as $q \neq a_w$

Comment: Thanks for the edit with explanation. I already gave +1.

Answer (score 0):

A reduction of problem (not a full answer):
Let us retain only the sequences of length 2004 that repeat infinitely often. Hence w.l.o.g there exists a smallest $\ell$ such that $a_k,a_{k+1},...,a_{k+\ell}$ is one of $\ell+1$ sequences each of length $\ell+1$ for every $k$ and each of these $\ell+1$ sequences repeat infinitely often in $0.a_1a_2...$.

let us look at the sequences appearing. Let $s_k = a_k,a_{k+1},...,a_{k+\ell}$.
We write as $s_k \rightarrow s_{k+1} \rightarrow s_{k+2}....$.
Now $s_k$ and $s_{k+1}$ has $\ell$ digits in common and $s_k$ is one of the $\ell+1$ sequences. Lets call these $\ell+1$ sequences as $g_1,...,g_{\ell+1}$.

Let $s_k = g_{\sigma(k)}$. Hence we have $g_{\sigma(k)} \rightarrow g_{\sigma(k+1)} \rightarrow g_{\sigma(k+2)}....$. Now all the $\ell+1$ sequences appear in this transitions. If $\sigma(k+\ell+1) = \sigma(k)$, forall $k$, then the digits repeat in $a_1....$ and hence a rational number. But if $\sigma(k+j) = \sigma(k)$ then it must be possible that two sequences transitions are possible i.e., say it must be possible that $g_1 \rightarrow g_2$ and $g_1 \rightarrow g_3$.
Hence there must be atleast 2 sequences $g_2,g_3$ which differ in exactly last element.
Now form the set of all such so called possible orbits $(g_m \rightarrow g_u.... g_i \rightarrow g_m)$ (no repitition in the transitions). The number is rational if there is exactly only one possible orbit $(g_1 \rightarrow g_u.... g_i \rightarrow g_1)$ (no repitition in the transitions) and no other orbit is possible. "In general" at a high level, we can use $2$ orbits satisfying certain properties and construct a number by placing these 2 orbits successively in various ways pretending these 2 orbits are mapped 0/1 such that the number is irrational.

Note that if there is a non-repeating orbit $(g_1 \rightarrow g_i ... \rightarrow g_m \rightarrow g_1)$ of length $u$ < $(\ell+1)$  then each element $g_j$ in the orbit can be generated by a single sequence of the form $(e_0,e_1,....,e_{\ell})$ and the orbit is generated by $$(e_0,...,e_{\ell}) \rightarrow ... \rightarrow (e_{(i:\ell)},e_{((\ell-u+1): (\ell-u+1+i-1))}) \rightarrow ...$$.

Since any sequence is reachable from any sequence, we have that all sequences $g_1,...,g_{\ell+1}$ are generated from a single sequence $(e_0,e_1,....,e_{\ell})$.

For every orbit of length $u$, involving $g_i = (m_0,m_1,....,m_{\ell})$, we have the condition $m_{(u:\ell)} = m_{(0:\ell-u)}$. This implies the sequence $(m_0,m_1,....,m_{\ell})$ is periodic with period $u$. Hence each sequence in a non-repeating orbit of length $u$ is periodic with period $u$. Similarly for other $g_j$.  Hence we have that every sequence $g_i$ is periodic with period $u_1,u_2,...$ where $u_i$ i s the length of some non-repeating orbit involving $g_i$. Note that every $g_i$ is generated by $(e_0,e_1,....,e_{\ell})$. Hence every sequence $g_i$ is generated from $(e_0,e_1,....,e_{\ell})$ after a series of periodic shifts of length $\ell_1,\ell_2,...,\ell_q$ w.r.t period $u_1,u_2,...,u_q$ for some $q \leq \frac{\ell+1}{2}$.

Try to proceed from this point.

Comment: If you yourself are not satisfied with your own post, you might temporarily delete it and improve your answer on computer/paper. By modifying your answer, you automatically modify the question. Remember, you are not writing a novel (=:

Comment: I think my post kind of led to the other answer which follows in the same way but using graph representation for orbits. Not sure if to take credit for almost solving or delete it. You guys suggest. I will delete my post if needed.